# Trying to add new user to database (MongoDB) getting this error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save a user to MongoDB database using post request as follow, but I got the error TypeError: User is not a function. I can't figure out anything wrong with it. The output says that error is present on the line  "  const user = new User(req.body);"
[postman output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvMm.png)  [nodejs output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbjbh.png)

is my userschema wrong or the export method is wrong.

```
const User = require("../models/user");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);
  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "NOT able to save user in DB"
      });
    }
    res.json({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      id: user._id
    });
  });
};

exports.signout = (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "User signout"
  });
};


//user schema
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');


var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        maxlenght:32,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname:{
        type: String,
        maxlenght:32,
        trim: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique:true
    },
    userinfo:{
        type:String,
        trim:true
    },
    encry_password:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
    },
    salt:String,
    role:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },
    purchases :{
        type:Array,
        default:[]
    }

} ,{ timestamps: true } );

userSchema.virtual("password")
    .set(function(password){
        this._password = password;
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        this.encry_password = this.securePassword(password);
    })
    .get(function(){
        return this._password;
    })

userSchema.methods = {
        authenticate: function(plainpassword){
            return this.securePassword(plainpassword) === this.encry_password;
    },

    securePassword: function (plainpassword){
        if(!plainpassword) return "";
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha256',this.salt)
            .update(plainpassword)
            .digest('hex');
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    }
};




module.export = mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the issue with the code.

Line 1: `const user = new User(req.body);`

Line 2:   `user.save((err, user) => {`

JS is now confused about `user` which is a constant variable to that of the `user` which is the return value of the save action.

So, to get rid of this, rename the return value of save action to something else like `responseUserObj`. Thus your above two lines of code should now be

```
const user = new User(req.body);
        user.save((err, responseUserObj) => {
```

Happy coding.